# ViewPager doesn't instantiate

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm having a weird problem and I can't figure out why my ViewPager won't instantiate. According to all kinds of SO questions and tutorials, I'm doing it correctly, but when I print to the stack, it looks like the instantiateItem() method doesn't run at all, even though I'm calling setAdapter(adapter) in the onCreateView of my parent fragment. Everything above the ViewPager inflates fine, but the ViewPager just shows blank nothing.

Here's the code.

```
public class Profile extends Fragment {

ListView userInfo;
FeedAdapter adapter;
ViewPager pager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_profile, container, false);
    ProfilePagerAdapter adapter = new ProfilePagerAdapter();
    pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.profileViewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);

    TextView userName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    userName.setText(Utility.userName);

    Log.i("Profile", "Fragment and Pager instantiated");

    return view;
}


private class ProfilePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    public ProfilePagerAdapter(){

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int resId = 0;

        switch(position){
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.news_feed;
            View view1 = inflater.inflate(resId,null);

            ListView feedList;
            FeedAdapter feedAdapter;

            feedList = (ListView) view1.findViewById(R.id.feedList);
            feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), Utility.newsFeed);
            feedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            feedList.setAdapter(feedAdapter);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView (view1,0);
            Log.i("Profile", "Instantiated case 0");
            return view1;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.splash;
            View view2 = inflater.inflate(resId,null);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(view2,0);
            Log.i("Profile", "Instantiated case 1");
            return view2;
        }

        return resId;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

And here's the xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/profileLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coverPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/grey_color" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePhoto"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/coverPhoto"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profilePhoto"
        android:text="User&apos;s Name"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/profilePhoto"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/profileViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/profileButtonBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're telling it you have 0 items:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes it execute the instantiateItem() code according to logcat, but I still don't see anything where the ViewPager is.

Comment: Nevermind. I just had to change the layout_height for the ViewPager to some number other than match_parent. Thanks.